# Using GregorianCalendar() to determine elapsed time in mm:ss format, what is happening with mm:ss format?

Tags: java

I've finished my degree and am experimenting now, trying to advance my understanding of Java.  Personally, the best way to learn is to do so I've started working on a project one piece at a time.  Basically, I want to determine and dynamically display the elapsed time the program has been running.  You'll notice I have a `JTextField` formatted to display the elapsed time and I have the `System.out.println()` method called to have a record of my overall output.

Here is the code:

```
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TimeFormat extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        JTextField btf = new JTextField(3);
        JPanel b = new JPanel();   
        JFrame f=new JFrame("");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        

        Thread clock = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                // Start time
                int m = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int s = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                // Begin loop to calculate elapsed time
                for(;;) {
                    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                    int mm = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    int ss = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                    // MM:SS format
                    if ((mm-m)<10 && (ss-s)<10) {
                        btf.setText("0"+(mm-m)+":0"+(ss-s));
                        System.out.println("0"+(mm-m)+":0"+(ss-s));
                    } else if ((mm-m)<10) {
                        btf.setText("0"+(mm-m)+":"+(ss-s));
                        System.out.println("0"+(mm-m)+":"+(ss-s));
                    } else {
                        btf.setText((mm-m)+":"+(ss-s));
                        System.out.println((mm-m)+":"+(ss-s));
                    }

                    try {
                        sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TimeFormat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        clock.start();

        b.add(btf);
        f.add(b);
        f.setSize(100, 100);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }  
}
```

The results will format correctly, for the most part.  The program will start at `00:00` and run well up to `00:53`.  At `00:54` I get `01:0-6` instead.  That will continue until `00:59 (01:0-1)`.  It will then resume normally at `01:00` up to `01:53`.  At that point I get `02:0-6`. Why will it not format correctly for those last six seconds of each minute?

```
00:00
...
00:53
01:0-6 (00:54)
...
01:0-1 (00:59)
01:00
...
01:53
02:0-6 (1:54)
...
02:0-1 (1:59)
02:00
...
```

I've been all over Google and the forums here the last four days trying to figure out how to dynamically display the time elapsed and this is the only one I've found that I can manipulate the easiest.  I've tried `JFormattedTextField`, `MaskFormatter`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and this current method in various combinations without success until now.  I've noticed several references to Joda Time being best for determining elapsed time.  I have not tried that yet but plan on it this week.  Those six seconds though...why?  I appreciate any and all insight.

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that `ss` is always greater than `s` and `mm` is always greater than `m` however this is not always true. E.g if you started your application at 01:59:59 then 2 seconds later at 02:01:01, `ss = 1` (less than s=`59`), `mm = 1` (less than m=`59`)

Instead of using Calendar you can use System.currentTimeMillis():

```
long t = System.currentTimeMillis()
...
long ms = System.currentTimeMillis() - t
long m = ms / 60000
long s = ms % 60000
```

Comment: Thank you!  Worked like a champ.  The only modification I needed to make was to divide (ms % 60000) by 1000 to produce the desired result (00 to 59).